# Gamma matrix, four derivative exchange

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I'm trying to study about the dirac equation, and the adjoint of it.
I have few questions about that.

**After finishing writing, I realized that all $\partial ^\mu$ should be $\partial_\mu$.

1.
$$
\gamma^\mu \partial^\mu = \partial^\mu \gamma ^\mu
$$
Is the above equation correct?

Comment: Hello! Please only ask one question per post – otherwise it might get closed due to lack of focus. You can always [edit] your question or [ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new one. Thanks!

Comment: If you know your post has a typo, why wouldn’t you fix it?